# Como versionar projetos de front-end?

Tags: front-end, versionamento

Como versionar projetos de front-end?

[Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) traz as seguintes abordagens:

- MAJOR - quando você faz alterações de API incompatíveis
- MINOR - quando você adiciona funcionalidade de forma compatível com versões anteriores
- PATCH - quando faz correções de bugs compatíveis com versões anteriores. Etiquetas adicionais para pré-lançamento e metadados de compilação estão disponíveis como extensões ao formato MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.

Porém um artefato de frontend não possui APIs, fazendo com que os mesmos não quebrem compatibilidades para com quem os utiliza.

De que forma ficaria melhor para incrementar os números das versões de um front-end?

Caso meu frontend passe a consumir uma nova API de terceiros, seria uma alteração do tipo MAJOR?

Gostaria de sugestões.

Comment: O que você considera "um artefato de frontend"? dê alguns exemplos se possível.

Comment: Aqui estou me referindo à o projeto de frontend, no caso tudo que se encontra dentro do repositório de fontes.

Answer (score 2):

> *Semantic versioning* traz as seguintes abordagens: [...] porém um artefato de frontend não possui APIs, fazendo com que os mesmos não quebrem compatibilidades para com quem os utiliza.

Exato. *Semantic versioning* é utilizado para normalizar o comportamento de *dependências*. Um consumidor final não é uma dependência, portanto o modelo não se aplica - entretanto várias empresas realizam implementações casadas, mantendo o versionamento da UI em *lockstep* com a versão da API consumida.

> De que forma ficaria melhor para incrementar os números das versões de um frontend?

Se elas ocorrem ao mesmo tempo, utilize a mesma tag de versão da API. Caso não, fica a seu critério criar (ou reutilizar) uma definição de critérios de versionamento.

> Caso meu frontend passe a consumir uma nova API de terceiros, seria uma alteração do tipo MAJOR?

Fica a critério do projeto, já que *SV* não se aplica. A versão 2 de um app pode muito bem estar utilizando os mesmos *endpoints* da API da versão 1.

Comment: Abri a questão visando coletar sugestões de como versionar, os projetos onde eu atuo não necessariamente casam com apenas uma API, se tratando de microserviços um frontend pode utilizar APIs de vários backends distintos, por isso não faz sentido lançar versões casadas, que ao meu ver não faz muito sentido em outras ocasiões também.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei um artigo bacana que sugere algumas regras para versionar frontends, o artigo diz basicamente o seguinte:

Dada a importância dos requisitos de instalação de um aplicativo para usuários instaladores, proponho que o Semver seja usado para aplicativos de versão final usando os requisitos de instalação como API pública com usuários instaladores como consumidores desta API. Na prática, incremente:

- MAJOR quando você faz alterações de API incompatíveis (por exemplo, os usuários do instalador devem modificar sua infraestrutura (telefone / tablet / PC / web-server / firewall config / etc) de alguma forma)
- MINOR quando você adiciona funcionalidade de forma compatível com versões anteriores (por exemplo, passando dados adicionais para uma API já provisionada ou adicionando qualquer funcionalidade de usuário final que não afete os requisitos de instalação)
- PATCH quando você faz correções de erros compatíveis com versões anteriores (por exemplo, corrigindo qualquer erro de usuário final que não afete os requisitos de instalação).